# Memory leak in fgets

Tags: php

I have been playing with PHP sockets for some days when making a simple IRC bot for some other projects, the bot is up and running but i noticed that after a couple of hours it will have eaten up all memory available.

I have been doing some debugging with memory_get_usage() and after making sure that i null out all variables i use within my loops, the only thing that causes an increase in memory usage is "fgets()", and i cannot seem to figure out why it wont release its memory after using it.

Any ideas of what i have been doing wrong?

Psudo-code:

```
$this->socket = stream_socket_client(server, port);
stream_set_blocking($this->socket, 0);
stream_set_timeout($this->socket, 600);

while(true) {
  usleep(500000);
  $data = fgets($this->socket, 8192);
  *work with data if strlen > 0*
  $data = null;
}
```

Note that i have disabled blocking so that the bot can do some background tasks even when there are no activity on the channels it is watching.

Memory usage before and after calling fgets (the same result with stream_get_line):

```
int(959504)
string(0) "" //Data returned from gets
int(967736)
```

Note that i am testing against an SSL-server, could this be some kind of SSL "overflow"?

Or if you want to look at the whole code for yourself: https://github.com/Ueland/VikingBot

Comment: don't want flock() to block while locking

Answer (score 1):

According to https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=38962 it's bug which is reproduced in a specific php 5.2.6 version. So if you use higher version you can report about your findings :)

Comment: You're pointing at a bug reported on PHP4.0beta3 in '00? With no mention of php 5.2.6?

Comment: @Marc-b Sorry, link from another tab :)

Comment: Strange part is, if i try to run the bug test case it wont give me that issue, not even if i make a new script that simply reads /dev/urandom. But as soon as i try to pull data from a IRC server i get 160 bytes more memory usage per fgets.

Answer (score 0):

Simply setting a variable to null doesn't release the memory the previous data was using. It simply disconnects the data from the variable. At some point in the future, the PHP garbage collector MAY kick in and actually free up the memory, but it's not guaranteed to do so. Garbage collection is a very expensive operation, CPU-usage-wise, and PHP will not run the GC unless it absolutely has to. Usually this'd be when memory usage gets close to the `memory_limit` setting.

You can try to force a GC run via `gc_collect_cycles()`

Comment: I have even tried to force GC manually and have even added automatic calls to gc_collect_cycles() when free memory becomes low, but no dice. The memory gets exhausted no matter what. All the nulls in the code is rather the result of me trying to make sure that all that i can do memory-wise is done.

Answer (score 0):

use stream_get_line() instead of fgets()

Comment: Both fgets and stream_get_line gives me additional 160bytes of data for each time i call them and they have no data to return.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out at last. I realized that instead of doing a "while(true)" i used a function that only called itself when it was done, and therefore keeping a reference of itself laying around. Dunno why i didnt notice it before now, but at least now the memory usage keeps the same for every round. ;)

Thanks for all suggestions!